# PySpark: Output of OneHotEncoder looks odd

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, one-hot-encoding

The Spark documentation contains [a PySpark example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#onehotencoder) for its `OneHotEncoder`:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "a"),
    (1, "b"),
    (2, "c"),
    (3, "a"),
    (4, "a"),
    (5, "c")
], ["id", "category"])

stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="category", outputCol="categoryIndex")
model = stringIndexer.fit(df)
indexed = model.transform(df)

encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="categoryIndex", outputCol="categoryVec")
encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
encoded.show()
```

I was expecting the column `categoryVec` to look like this:

```
[0.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 1.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 1.0]
```

But `categoryVec` actually looks like this:

```
(2, [0], [1.0])
    (2, [], [])
(2, [1], [1.0])
(2, [0], [1.0])
(2, [0], [1.0])
(2, [1], [1.0])
```

What does this mean? How should I read this output, and what is the reasoning behind this somewhat odd format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing odd here. These are just `SparseVectors` where:

- The first element is size of the vector
- The first array `[...]` is a list of indices.
- The second array is the list of values.

Indices not explicitly listed are 0.0.